# Is the change of displacement with respect to the radius at the origin of a cylinder always equal to zero if the load is symmetric?

Tags: symmetry, continuum-mechanics, displacement

Consider a cylinder under dynamic uniform axial pressure as shown below.

[image]

At the radial origin exists non-zero axial displacement $u_z(t,0,z)$. I know from the mathematical definition of symmetry that the first-order derivative of a function at its origin is zero if the function is symmetric with respect to the origin. In this case, that means:

$$ {\partial u_z(t, r, z)\over\partial r }\Bigg|_{r=0}=0 \tag 1$$

I can't really visualize this physical phenomenon, but it makes sense to me that this condition also applies to higher-order radial partial derivatives of $u_z$.

My question is, are all higher-order radial partial derivatives of $u_z$ equal to zero at its radial origin, or does this apply only to the first-order radial partial derivative?

Comment: What are the boundary conditions of the other end of the cylinder? Where is the origin of coordinates in your schematic?

Comment: At the bottom, the cylinder is fixed which means that there are no displacements in the $r$ and $z$ directions. The coordinate system origin is also at the center of the bottom base of the cylinder. I will edit the question to include this information